# SED command works in command line but not inside script [file not found error]

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I'm trying to do a really simple task: I want to replace an occurrence of a word in the header of a CSV file with another word. Stop.

I also want this to be done for all CSVs in my current folder.

If I run this in command line it works perfectly

```
sed -i 's/CLOUD_RESOURCE_CONSUMPTION_RATE/CLOUD_RES_CONSUMPTION_RATE/' *.csv
```

But if I run it in a shell script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
sed -i 's/CLOUD_RESOURCE_CONSUMPTION_RATE/CLOUD_RES_CONSUMPTION_RATE/' *.csv
```

I get the error: `No such file or directory` and this file appears in my directory [image].

What am I doing wrong? I'm sure it's something silly but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Could you please include the full error message? Did you write your script on a Windows machine?

Comment: It sounds like the working directory is different in the two scenarios. Whatever the working directory is when you run the script, it doesn't contain any files with a `csv` extension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have a stray character on the end of the `sed` line in your `bash` script. Was the script written using a Windows editor? If so, I suspect there is a carriage return on the end. I can replicate your error if I put a carriage return in.

Try running

```
dos2unix <scriptname>
```

and re-running.

If `dos2unix` doesn't work it wasn't a carriage return, and I'd suggest retyping the whole script into a new file using `nano` or `vim` to remove the stray.

Comment: It was as you said. I've ran the `dos2unix` command and not it's working perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Can you write your script like this

```
 sed -i 's/CLOUD_RESOURCE_CONSUMPTION_RATE/CLOUD_RES_CONSUMPTION_RATE/' <path to folder having csv files>/*.csv
```

Comment: I tried. Same result.
Even if I type a single file name instead of the "*.csv"